# Ignite Cluster co-location advantage doesn't seem possible under Kubernetes scaling with shared data storage and WAL. Any problems?

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I have managed to successfully scale up and down an Ignite cluster under a Kubernetes cluster.

Increasing the number of "replicas" creates new Ignite PODs which join the cluster using "Kubernetes IP Finder".

Decreasing the number of replicas drops some PODs and the respective Ignite nodes leave the Ignite cluster.

This is perfect, I can increase and decrease the size of the Ignite cluster on demand.

So far I haven't enabled "persistence" in my Ignite cluster.

But, if the Ignite nodes had "persistence" enabled then they would have to share the data storage as the nodes are not pre-defined but dynamic.
This implies that each Ignite node wouldn't have its own data anymore and therefore co-location is not possible.
How would Ignite choose to split the work?

Also, since all nodes are sharing the same storage they will start to compete for access to the data storage and the WAL.
Wouldn't this become a performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a shared drive doesn’t influence the data partitioning algorithm and affinity co-location. Each node creates a unique folder on that shared drive for data it’s responsible for.

It’s right that the shared drive can become a bottleneck. You need to arrange several drives and spread them among pods. GridGain folks might have more specific recommendations as long as they provide an Ignite managed service. Try to get insights from them: https://www.gridgain.com/products/managed-services/gridgain-nebula

Comment: I was more considering of ways to make the cluster grow when more resources are needed and shrink when fewer resources are required.

I didn't know that each node creates its own folder in the shared data storage.
This implies that I can scale up the cluster.
But, if I scale down I may inevitably lose data.

I agree with bottleneck concerns though and the managed service approach.

Finally, it feels best having each node/POD explicitly configured, with its own data store etc.

Comment: "GridGain and Apache Ignite Operator for Kubernetes" seems to be suitable for orchestrated Ignite cluster resize and management.

see https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator/operator

Again, scaling-up sounds very positive, but, how about scaling-down?
I guess I will have to experiment with "GridGain and Apache Ignite Operator for Kubernetes" to find out or ask the questino to the related groups.